# caching data until a specified time

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, werkzeug

Here's the idea: I have a web application which will read data from files, manipulate it, and JSONify it for javascript to pretty up.

The data is fetched by a cron which will run a python script that makes the files by querying a database and writing it. However, this data will only be fetched at specific, configurable times.

My goal is to cache the data until the cron runs. Is there a way to cache until a specified time?

Comment: If by cache, you mean just storing the JSON output on the server until the next cron run, why not just save it to the filesystem?  As the cron finishes running, it just saves the 'new' json over it?

Comment: You might want to look at a job dispatch system like celery. It condenses your problem down to a very easy set of API calls and is being used all over the place for similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try using python packages which stores data in your designated cache databases, the package will store all responses with headers and cookies into demo_cache.sqlite database.
Write:

```
import requests
import requests_cache

requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache')
```

Here is the documentation for the package [requests-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache)

2) You can also check [Beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this pupose.